# webservices implemetation design

Tags: web-services, design-patterns

I am writing a Rest Web Services. 
I am not great at designing. 
At present i wanted to know the service handler should be singleton or static.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{input}" ,method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String getOutput(@PathVariable String input){

ResourceRestService.getInstance().outPutService().getOutput(input);
}
```

Is using singleton instance of ResourceRestService or OutputService correct in this case?
Does it cause any performance overhead when the number of requests increases if yes then what should be the solution?

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is a standard, no issues. Since it is a singleton and non thread safe, the class should not maintain state, all it has to do is to get request and send response. If the number of requests increase, you may have to use clustered environment(apache mod_jk etc.,)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Small doubt, if a request has come and it is being processed in getOutput method and at the same time new request comes, does the new request has to wait till the first request completes as the class is singleton ?

Comment: Nope. The server creates another thread for you. So, the code is executed concurrently. You don't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

You Service method should not be a singleton unless there is a specific need for you to do you like in case of making it Thread Safe or so,

You should rather make it static.

When no of requests increases there are quite a few scenarios that you may need to consider for you to scale, A non-exhaustive list is as below
1. Is it due to database layer? no of records, db performance etc etc
2. Is it due to service layer? amt of processing at service layer due to various reason
3. Is it due to server capability? Max no of requests it could handle

so on..